# camera_calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, face-recognition, ros-fuerte, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i try to make sure that my monocular camera is publishing images over ROS by typing the """rostopic list """
the following error appear """ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!
"""""" , How Can I solve that ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164716/camera_calibration/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means roscore is not running or you have some network issues. Check if roscore is running and if the problem persists, refer to http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup for problems with your network.

---

Originally posted by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) with karma: 380 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-05-14**:
Thnx for your help ;
I  run the "" roscore" the topics published """/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_raw"""
but the actual output for me is ""/rosout
/rosout_agg """  ,,, How can I solve this ???

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-05-14**:
Just to clarify - you expect the output to be "/camera/camera_info   /camera/image_raw", but the actual output is "/rosout /rosout_agg"? If so, you need to make sure the nodes that publish or subscribe to "/camera/camera_info   /camera/image_raw" are running. Run roscore and "rosnode list" to check.

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-05-14**:
the only output after ""rosnode list" is  """ /rosout """ ????

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-05-14**:
Okay so that means you haven't started your nodes. You need to do "rosrun package_name node_name". Read the node tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes it should help you.